# SVN Override remote files absolutely by local files

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse

I am using SVN in Eclipse (Subclipse). It is frustrating to spend two hours to figure out (apparently simple task) how to absolutely commit your local files to repository (with no comparisons, no updates, without accepting any incoming change), and still no success. Can stackoverflowers help me out here?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Every time I try to commit, it first asks me to update. When I update, it automatically merges non-conflicting changes from both sides, that I do not want. Is there anyway to update and commit without merging changes from both sides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I did it:

1. Exported working copy to another directory.
2. SVN->Delete the current working copy.
3. SVN->Commit current working copy.
4. Copied the exported files back into the working directory.
5. SVN->Add copied files.
6. SVN->Commit copied files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following:

1. Export a your working copy to another directory (SVN has an export command for that)
2. Update your working copy
3. Copy the exported files over it.

Comment: How am I supposed to copy(step 3)? Manually from window explorer or is there any SVN specific way of doing it?

Comment: Be aware that by doing this you will be clobbering all your coworker's changes...  and they will **hate** you.

Comment: @craftsman: No specific way. Just use the regular explorer and copy the files, overwriting everything.